General solution of $\cos(3\theta) - \cos(\theta) = 0$
General solution of $\cos(3\theta) - \cos(\theta) = 0$
Method 1:
$$4\cos^{3}(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta) - \cos(\theta) = 0$$
$$4\cos^{3}(\theta) - 4\cos(\theta) = 0$$
$$4\cos(\theta) (\cos^{2} (\theta) - 1) = 0$$
$$\cos(\theta) (\cos^{2} (\theta) - 1) = 0$$
From here,
Either $$\cos(\theta) = 0$$ thus $$\theta = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$$
Or $$\cos^{2} (\theta) - 1 = 0$$
$$\cos^{2} (\theta) = 1$$
$$\cos^{2} (\theta) = \cos^{2} (0)$$
$$\theta = n\pi$$
Method 2:
$$2\sin(2\theta).\sin(\theta) = 0$$
$$\sin(2\theta).\sin(\theta) = 0$$
Either $$\sin(2\theta) = 0$$
$$2\theta = n\pi$$
$$\theta = \frac{n\pi}{2}$$
Or
$$\sin(\theta) = 0$$
$$\theta = n\pi$$
Which among the two methods is correct? If both methods are correct, why do we get different answers?

both are correct. why do you think the answers are different?

Why not answer it yourself?  (1) Take a $\theta$ from the first list that is not in the second, and see what happens when it is used in the second argument.  And/or (2) Take a $\theta$ from the second list not in the first and see what happens when it is used in the first argument.  (3)  If (as Soham suggests) you cannot find such $\theta$, you are done.

You will notice, if you do what @GEdgar suggests, that both list can be written in general form as ${k\pi}/{2}$

The solutions are $\ldots, -\pi,-\frac12\pi, 0, \frac12\pi, \pi,\frac32\pi,2\pi,\ldots$

You can also see, that in the first case, your solutions are nothing but $\text{odd}\times{\pi}/2$ and $\text{even}\times{\pi}/2$. And in the second case, the first form already contains the second

You first solution set $\{\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2},n\pi\}$ is equal to the second $\{\frac{n\pi}{2},n\pi\}$.

Plugging in the candidate solution angles into the original equation, we see that any integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (90°) will satisfy it.
Your two solutions are actually the same.  Method 1 gives:
$$\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} = \{ \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{5\pi}{2}, \frac{7\pi}{2}, \dots\}$$
$$n\pi = \{ \pi, 2\pi, 3\pi, 4\pi, \dots \}$$
And taking the union of these sets gives $\{ \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi, \frac{5\pi}{2}, 3\pi, \frac{7\pi}{2}, 4\pi, \dots\}$
Method 2 gives:
$$\frac{n\pi}{2} = \{ \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi,  \dots\}$$
$$n\pi = \{ \pi, 2\pi, 3\pi, 4\pi, \dots \}$$
And taking the union of these two sets gives $\{ \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi, \frac{5\pi}{2}, 3\pi, \frac{7\pi}{2}, 4\pi, \dots\}$.
So, either method gives you the same solutions.  The only difference is that $\sin(2\theta) = 0$ is satisfied by whole multiples of $\pi$ while $\cos(\theta) = 0$ is satisfied only by odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but since both methods already include $\theta = n\pi$ as a solution, the “extra” solutions of Method 2 end up being redundant.
